# MySQL to Oracle Query

Tags: oracle, group-by, pivot

Recently our Database changed from MySQL to Oracle. I am trying to convert one query to oracle that already using in MySQL to generate report. Problem is the format of timestamp field in oracle is VARCHAR2 (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS). I am looking for the equivalent output in oracle. Please help me to achieve it.

Below code is in MySQL. I am looking for the equivalent code in oracle.

```
select date_format(ourTimestamp, '%Y / %m') as "Month",
       sum(unix_timestamp(AppliedTime) - unix_timestamp(ApprovedTime) < 24 * 3600)  as "0 - 24 hrs",
       sum(    (unix_timestamp(AppliedTime) - unix_timestamp(ApprovedTime) >= 24 * 3600) and (unix_timestamp(AppliedTime) - unix_timestamp(ApprovedTime) < 48 * 3600)) as "24 - 48 hrs", 
       sum(    (unix_timestamp(AppliedTime) - unix_timestamp(ApprovedTime) >= 48 *  3600) and (unix_timestamp(AppliedTime) - unix_timestamp(ApprovedTime) < 72 *  3600)) as "48 - 72 hrs",   
       count(*) as "Total"    
from Order    
where AppliedTimeis not null   
  and Type in ('SJ')    
  and ourTimestamp like '201601%'   
group by "Month" 
order by "Month";
```

Expected Output:

```
Month      0-24 hrs      24 - 48 hrs      48- 72 hrs      Total
2017/01    200           845              483              ...
```

and so on.

Comment: Oracle datatype for timestamp is `TIMESTAMP`. You probably did not migrate from MySQL to Oracle for storing timestamps as character strings...

Comment: Use [TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found solution. I used (to_date(AppliedTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')-to_date(ApprovedTime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')